# AJAX request not submitting my form

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have an ajax request which is used to submit a form.

```
$('#position'+i).change(function () { 
        var data = $(this).attr('value');
        var form = $('#pages_form');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: data,
            succes: alert('Postion has been saved')
        });
    });
```

It dosent seem to want to go the the url weather I hard code it or use the form action attribute. What do I need to do to get this to submit my form.

Its weird because if I hit enter it will submit the form but it will bypass the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

```
var form = $('pages_form');
```

This is bad, what sort of selector is this, theres no pages_from tag, as far as I know.
It should be

```
var form = $('#pages_form');
```

if its id.

If class then

```
 var form = $('.pages_form');
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt realize i left the pound sign out.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the call back works also you had success misspelled. You pass a function name or an anonymous function to the success method.

Working version:

```
$('#position'+i).change(function () { 
        var data = $(this).attr('value');
        var form = $('#pages_form'); // Is this an id?
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: data,
            success: function () {
               alert('Postion has been saved');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I chnaged the callback but it still doesn't submit my form

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely lies with the selector you use to get the form:

```
var form = $('pages_form');
```

There is no **html tag** with the name `pages_form` ;)

Also your way of specifying the callback is just plainly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of corrections:

```
var form = $('pages_form');
```

is not referring to a valid element. If 'pages_form' is the id of your form, then you need to use this:

```
var form = $('#pages_form');
```

Also, you spelled wrong 'success', and it doesn't have the format needed. Change that line to

```
success: function() {alert('Postion has been saved');}
```

I think after those are fixed your code should work. :)

Ok, then a few validations are needed, although they may seem obvious.

1. Make sure i contains a value and that there's an input element with the corresponding id, so if i equals 1, then you have an input element with the id 'position1'.
2. Make sure your form has the correct action attribute correctly set.

Comment: made all the changes but still not submitting

Comment: Yea a coded an alert to make sure the data being sent over is correct and to make sure that the correct textbox is sent over and everything is correct it just wont submit the form. Still not luck

Comment: Why not just use form.submit() instead of the whole ajax call? Unless you want to ignore other fields inside that form...

Comment: yea I think thats the route Im going to take thanks for your time I really appreciated it.

Comment: I just tried your code with the recommended fixes and it runs the ajax call upon updating the input box.. give it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/63P2r/